# Sklearn importing error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to import preprocessing, model selection and svm from sklearn, but I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\SmallYellowFace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\ProjectFiles\Machine_Learing.py",
>   line 4, in 
>           from sklearn import preprocessing, model_selection, svm
>         File "C:\Users\SmallYellowFace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py",
>   line 57, in 
>           from .base import clone
>         File "C:\Users\SmallYellowFace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py",
>   line 12, in 
>           from .utils.fixes import signature
>         File "C:\Users\SmallYellowFace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils__init__.py",
>   line 11, in 
>           from .validation import (as_float_array,
>         File "C:\Users\SmallYellowFace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 18, in 
>           from ..utils.fixes import signature
>         File "C:\Users\SmallYellowFace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py",
>   line 406, in 
>           if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
>       TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

I tired reinstall python and modules

Thanks!

Comment: `np_version` is a string and you're trying to compare it to a tuple of integers. please give more information about the format of `np_version`.

Comment: I'm using numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl

Comment: i got it to work! here's this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693558/typeerror-unorderable-types-str-int?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

```
>> pip install --upgrade numpy
```

OR

```
>> sudo pip3 install --upgrade numpy
```

SKlearn has a couple dependencies, numpy being the main one. Even if numpy is installed then it may be out-dated for your version of SKlearn